# bind mount to mysql docker container not working

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a mysql docker container with `container_name=mysql1`. When I run `docker exec -it mysqlsh` and look at the files using `ls` command, i see the following files.

```
bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  entrypoint.sh  etc  healthcheck.sh  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I want to bind mount some of these folders in my host machine, inside the directory where the docker-compose file is being run from.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql1:
    container_name: mysql1
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = 'root'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/etc
```

But tis is giving me the following error:

```
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Network poc_1_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 ⠿ Container mysql1       Created                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to mysql1
mysql1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.28-1.2.7-server
mysql1  | [Entrypoint] Initializing database
mysql1  | [Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
mysql1  | [Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
mysql1  | 2022-02-05T16:36:18.356881Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) initializing of server in progress as process 18
mysql1  | 2022-02-05T16:36:18.359651Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010124] [Server] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user exists!
mysql1  | 2022-02-05T16:36:18.359664Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
mysql1  | 2022-02-05T16:36:18.359700Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql1  | 2022-02-05T16:36:18.359754Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql1 exited with code 1
```

What is happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: What's the use case? Why do you want to mount `/etc` locally? I can't see the use for it.

Comment: Actually its not just `/etc`,  `var/lib/mysql` as well. Basically I need the `.pid` as well as some other files that lie inside `var/lib/mysql`. I am trying to setup `Vitess` with an unmanaged mysql server.